# Is UUID different for all devices?

Tags: android, ios, hardware, uuid, smartphone

Let's say there are a hundred iPhones and one hundred Android phones.

1. Are they going to have two hundred different UUIDs?
2. Is the UUID of a smartphone permanent?  It can never be changed?

Thanks a lot, Stack Overflow!!

Comment: UUID is short for Universally Unique Identifier

Comment: What do you mean by UUID?  The device ID or a UUID that you create from a call to a library such as NSUUID on iOS?

Comment: Paulw11 I meant this one device.uuid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull out as many UUIDs as you want. The odds of you getting the same UUID again are a trillion to 1.